# Save inputText value in Shiny as a String

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do a simple thing using Shiny but I must be missing some fundamental knowledge as I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I have a simple `textInput` field on the `UI` side

```
textInput(inputId = "user_keyword", label = "Enter title", value = "Leon", width = "100%")
```

Now on the `server` side, I want to concatenate the user input into a URL, for example

```
user_url <- reactive({ paste0("https://www.imdb.com/title/", input$user_keyword) })
```

However, I am either getting the error `can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'closure'` or `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.`

But in the docs for textInput it says

> Server value
> A character string of the text input. The default value is "" unless value is provided.

What is wrong?

EDIT: A reproducible code.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

user_agent <- user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
                         AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
my_session <- html_session("https://www.imdb.com", user_agent)

get_title_overview <- function(title_link) {
  title_page <- my_session %>% jump_to(title_link)
}

my.ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "MovieTitles"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    textInput(inputId = "user_keyword", label = "Enter title", value = "Leon", width = "100%")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

my.server <- function(input, output, session) {
  user_url <- reactive({ paste0("https://www.imdb.com/title/", input$user_keyword) })
  title_details <- data.frame(get_title_overview(user_url()))
}  
  
shinyApp(ui = my.ui, server = my.server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code regarding the `textInput` and creating `user_url` is correct. However, `user_url` is a reactive (basically a function), so to access its value you need to use `user_url()`. The errormessage indicates that somewhere in your code you try to access the value with `user_url` instead. See the code below for a working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(inputId = "user_keyword", label = "Enter title", value = "Leon", width = "100%"),
  
  textOutput("test_out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  user_url <- reactive({ paste0("https://www.imdb.com/title/", input$user_keyword) })
  
  output$test_out <- renderText({
    user_url()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, I have exactly this setup but I don't want to use the ´user_url´ as an output to the dashboard but as a variable to input into other functions. I am using user_url() but it's not working

Comment: I am using the user_url inside another function 
    get_keyword_overview <- function(keyword_link) {
       keyword_page <- my_session %>% jump_to(keyword_link)

Comment: It's no problem to use `user_url()` in a function. To better help you, please edit your question with the code that actually gives you the error.

Comment: OK, I've added a reproducible code now that doesn't lead to anywhere (entire app is a lot of rows) but generates the error message.

Comment: You're using `user_url()` without a reactive context (e.g. `observe`/`observeEvent`/`reactive`/`renderX`). This is not possible and leads to the error. For more information about reactivity see https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html

Comment: OK, now I have read up more but I still don't get it. I tried enclosing the whole data transformation inside a reactive expression and I've tried using the reactiveEvent function but I still cannot get it to work. Can you explain more what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: In the above code, `title_details <- data.frame(get_title_overview(user_url()))` is directly in the server, so it's not inside a reactive context. You can make it reactive by using a reactive: `title_details <- reactive({data.frame(get_title_overview(user_url()))})`. You can also edit your above code to show what you've tried

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out now. The problem was that I had misunderstood the reactivity concept. I thought that if you made a single variable reactive, the rest of the code could use that variable, in my case `user_url()` directly. 

Instead, I must make all subsequent data.frames etc each reactive as well for the whole code to work.